# Python program stops after executing subprocess.Popen once

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess

I am trying to execute a command line program multiple times using a loop in python.Naturally I used subprocess module for this task.But on executing the python script the command line program runs once and then stops.Neither does it run again,nor does it return to the python script.Below is the loop I wrote.'commandline' is the command I am running along with its arguments

```
for i in range(len(final)):
    ss=str(final[i][0])
    endpos=str(final[i][1])
    op='/home/nishant/op'+str(i)
    commandline='/home/nishant/project/LOOV/build/./LOOV -v vid -output op -ss ss -endpos endpos -lang eng -print_text'
    subprocess.Popen(commandline,shell=True).communicate()
```

Comment: You can't issue a `commandline` like that, it needs to be a list of arguments, not a list with one string that contains them all. Also, why do you `communicate()` at all? it seems without purpose here

Comment: yes,I had earlier used a list of arguments as you suggest.But then in the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html) I read that when shell is set to True,I have to pass the exact command and not a list of arguments.

Comment: Even if that is true, you have multiple variables like `ss` and `endpos` that you don't even give in your command, they are just written as strings as well

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `check_output` if you want your command to be executed, waited on and checked for a code 0 exit (no errors encountered) like this:

```
import subprocess
your_command = 'you command(s) here'
subprocess.check_output(your_command, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
A = subprocess.Popen("command", shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
print(A.communicate)
```

I'm pretty sure you can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

**Try [Plumbum](https://plumbum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).**

```
pip install plumbum
```

As I do not know its context, I developed a small example with the `ifconfig` command, composed in a loop for.

```
from plumbum.cmd import grep, ifconfig
from plumbum import FG, BG

lst = ['Link', 'inet', 'LOOPBACK', 'BROADCAST', '127', 'Eth']

for l in lst:
    command = ifconfig | grep[l]
    f = command & BG
    output = f.stdout
    print (output)
```

Output:

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 02:42:cd:ab:75:e2  
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 10:c3:7b:c4:21:e4  
          endereço inet6: fe80::8267:7328:8542:3434/64 Escopo:Link
lo        Link encap:Loopback Local  

          inet end.: 172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Masc:255.255.0.0
          inet end.: 192.168.1.34  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Masc:255.255.0.0
          endereço inet6: fe80::8267:7328:8542:3434/64 Escopo:Link
          inet end.: 127.0.0.1  Masc:255.0.0.0
          endereço inet6: ::1/128 Escopo:Máquina

          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Métrica:1

          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1

          inet end.: 127.0.0.1  Masc:255.0.0.0

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 02:42:cd:ab:75:e2  
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 10:c3:7b:c4:21:e4
```